# Passing a string description of an Angular scope variable to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a dynamic variable to an angular directive. I can come up w/ a string describing the variable I am after.  But I cannot bind that string to the actual Angular scope variable.

**my_app.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("my_app");
  app.controller("MyController", [ "$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.my_data = {
      name: "bob",
      display_detail: false,
      children: [
        {
          name: "fred",
          display_detail: false
        },
        {
          name: "joe",
          display_detail: true
        }
      ]        
    }

    app.directive('myDirective', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: "EAC",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                
                var model = attrs["modelToWatch"];
                var watched_name = model + ".display_detail";
                scope.$watch(watched_name, function (is_displayed) {
                    if (is_displayed) {
                      // do something clever w/ $http...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

**my_template.html:**

```
<div ng-app="my_app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <my_directive model_to_watch="my_data.children[1]"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that the string "my_data.children[1]" gets passed to the directive.  My goal is to somehow evaluate this and wind up with the actual model (the one named "joe" above).

Comment: I'm not sure why wouldn't just pass the data itself, rather than passing a string which represents the scope property that contains the data. But if you want to keep that approach, you're going to have to add some logic to your directive in the link function. You have the scope object, and you have the property, so you'll have to do something like var watched_name = scope["my_data"] (aka scope[model.split(".")[0]]), then watched_name = watched_name.children[1].display_detail , etc etc

Comment: You can look at [$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - $eval is helping... If I call `$scope.$eval("my_data.children[1]")` it correctly returns the scope variable.  But then if I try to access "name" or "display_detail" from that variable I get undefined.

Comment: @matmo - This is a contrived example.  The directive gets called w/in a loop of Django templates.  The actual name of the data is unknown beforehand.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - your suggestion of $eval did the trick.  While, trying to print ".display_detail" to the console returned undefined, adding a $watch to it seems to work.  If you restate your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Feel free to edit my answer to match the specifics of how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you have a string and want to get the scope value corresponding to it, you can use [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval) on `$scope` to get that information. So, in your case, something like this might work:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                
    var model = attrs["modelToWatch"];
    var watched_name = model.display_detail;

    scope.$watch(scope.$eval(watched_name), function (is_displayed) {
        if (is_displayed) {
          // do something clever w/ $http...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pass it into the directive's scope?

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        scope: {
            watchedName: '='
        },
        restrict: "EAC",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.watchedName.display_detail, function (is_displayed) {
                if (is_displayed) {
                  // do something clever w/ $http...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and

`<my-directive watched-name="my_data.children[1]"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.$parent.$watch and pass the attrs value as the first argument, i.e.

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "EAC",
        link: (scope, elem, attrs) => {
            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs["modelToWatch"], function(newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    // fancy http ajax method here
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```